# Buttons and data hides after jpanel is minimized horizontally..What can be the solution?

Tags: java, swing

When panel is minimized horizontally , i cant see the buttons (data and buttons are not visible).

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(this.getContentPane());
scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(230,220));
```

Still i dont find horizontal scrollbar and also the data gets hidden.

Comment: You need to provide more details about the code surrounding those lines. Typically the container in which it's added, the layout used, etc. The more details you can provide, the better chances you have to get an answer.

Comment: Have you tried `JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS`

Answer (score 1):

You code creates a scroll pane, but you never add the scroll pane to the frame.

scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

These lines are not needed as they are the default values when you create a scroll pane.

In order to see scrollbars the scroll pane must be added to the frame. So your code might be something like:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(this.getContentPane());
setContentPane(scrollPane);
```

This code assumes you have already added the components to the content pane of the frame.

However, normally you don't add components to the content pane first. Normally your code would be something like:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(...);
panel.add(...);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( panel );
frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Read the Swing tutorial on How to Use Scroll Panes for more information and examples. Also, the forum is full of working examples.

Comment: But what about the data which is hiddened during minimization of jpanle horizontally?

Comment: @ShirinEpari, I already stated you don't need the "AS_NEEDED". We can't read code posted in a comment. Update your question to include a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.